# Character issue with the Bellefair Google font

Tags: fonts, google-fonts

I'm currently using the Bellefair font from Google for a project. However, I get these black inner lines on certain characters. Can anyone enlighten me to why this is happening?

[image: Font Example]

Comment: Not enough info. What URL?

Comment: You can see the url now. Didn't realize it wasn't posted the first time.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `font-weight: 400;` in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Change the tag wrapped around the text. I assume you made it some sort of heading like `<h1>`. Changing it to a `<p>` should fix the issue.